# What is BrowserGetter in JUnit?

Tags: automated-testing, junit, browsers, intellij

[image]I am a beginner for test automation and following the Test Automation University 'IntelliJ for Test Automation Engineers' course. In chapter 6.3 to create fields and variables use this 'BrowserGetter' keyword. But the code is not working and it shows as

> Cannot resolve symbol 'BrowserGetter'

This is the code used in the chapter and to solve this, how to import this **BrowserGetter** for the IntelliJ ?

`private BrowserGetter browserGetter = new BrowserGetter();`

Comment: Look at imports section and show us the line where that class is imported.

Comment: In the original code, it imports from the browser. `import browser.BrowserGetter;`

Comment: I believe you didn't completely follow the example. It seems that `browser.BrowserGetter` is part of that example implementation

Comment: First, I tried to import that by `private BrowserGetter browserGetter = new BrowserGetter();`. But that was not imported and then I tried to do it manually. Could you explain the mistake and this is the module I followed.  [https://testautomationu.applitools.com/intellij/chapter6.3.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of this course is arguable. As you can hear from the presentation (the link you mentioned in your comment) that class is a sort of Utility class that has been prepared by course developers (it is not the part of JUnit).

They briefly touch that class in the next video. However they do not describe it in details.

You can find missing code in their source code repository. For example the class you're asking about particularly can be found [here](https://github.com/iamalittletester/selenium-tutorial/blob/master/src/main/java/browser/BrowserGetter.java).